Converting function to tensorflow 2.x
def bidirectional_recurrent_layer_output_new(fw_cell, bw_cell, input_layer, sequence_len, scope=None):
if not isinstance(input_layer, tf.Tensor):
    raise ValueError("input_layer must be a TensorFlow tensor")

# Create a Bidirectional RNN layer
bidirectional_rnn = Bidirectional(RNN(fw_cell, return_state=True),
                                  backward_layer=RNN(bw_cell, return_sequences=True, return_state=True),
                                  merge_mode=None)

outputs = bidirectional_rnn(input_layer, mask=tf.sequence_mask(sequence_len))
fw_outputs, bw_outputs = outputs[0], outputs[1]
fw_state, bw_state = outputs[2], outputs[3]

def concatenate_state(fw_state, bw_state):
    if isinstance(fw_state, LSTMStateTuple):
        state_c = tf.concat((fw_state.c, bw_state.c), 1, name='bidirectional_concat_c')
        state_h = tf.concat((fw_state.h, bw_state.h), 1, name='bidirectional_concat_h')
        state = LSTMStateTuple(c=state_c, h=state_h)
        return state
    elif isinstance(fw_state, tf.Tensor):
        state = tf.concat((fw_state, bw_state), 1,
                          name='bidirectional_concat')
        return state
    elif (isinstance(fw_state, tuple) and
              isinstance(bw_state, tuple) and
                  len(fw_state) == len(bw_state)):
        # multilayer
        state = tuple(concatenate_state(fw, bw)
                      for fw, bw in zip(fw_state, bw_state))
        return state

    else:
        raise ValueError(
            'unknown state type: {}'.format((fw_state, bw_state)))

state = concatenate_state(fw_state, bw_state)
return outputs, state

the above code is giving the following error.
AttributeError: 'BNLSTMCell' object has no attribute '_name'. Did you mean: 'name'?
How to resolve it?
File "C:\Users\anjal\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 501, in get_config
config = {'name': self.name, 'trainable': self.trainable}
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\anjal\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 858, in name
return self._name
^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'BNLSTMCell' object has no attribute '_name'. Did you mean: 'name'?
